# Get object from array by specifc index using variable

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, filter

I have 1 variable and 1 array. The array contains any number of numbers, from 0 to 10 - like such: 0,1,2,3,4,5 and so on.

My variable contains 1 number, let's say 4 - I want to use the variable to get the number at index 4 in the array, minus 1. So in the above examples, I would get 2.

How can I go about creating a variable with that number? I have tried:

```
var goBack = $(userBack2).index(place-1);
```

Where ***`goBack`*** is the variable I am creating, ***`userBack2`*** is the array containing my numbers and ***`place`*** is my variable determining what index I need.

I know that the syntax is completely wrong, that index might not be correct to use here, but I simply cannot figure out how to do it. Do I need to use filter? if so, how?

Comment: `alert(ar[variable - 1])`?

Comment: `var goBack = userBack2[place-1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply get value from array using bracket notation

```
var goBack = userBack2[place - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don't need to use jquery anymore. Native javascript is enough.

```
var items = [0, 1, 2, ..., 10];
var num = 4;
var goBack = items[num - 1];
```